# Duplicate Block Object with tile entity when place the block

Tags: minecraft-forge

I created a Forge block, but when I test it, when I place it and right-click on it, I get duplicate messages, one normal and one without any update. No sub-blocks are set, and the registration is done in the same way as block + tile.

```
    public boolean onBlockActivated(BlockArgHolder holder, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ) {
        BlockPos blockPos = holder.getBlockPos();
        TileEntity te = holder.getWorld().getTileEntity(holder.getBlockPos());
        if (te instanceof TileEntityATSControllerBase)
            ((TileEntityATSControllerBase)te).setPlayer(holder.getPlayer());
        holder.getPlayer().sendMessage(new TextComponentString(String.format("Block Position\n X:%d, Y:%d, Z:%d", blockPos.getX(),blockPos.getY(),blockPos.getZ())));
blockPos.getX(), blockPos.getY(), blockPos.getZ());
        return true;
    }
```

This the pic of game logger:
[See Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka0lL.png)

Thanks!